# MySQL query is extremely slow

Tags: mysql

I have a complex SQL query that linked 6 tables and I found out that it takes about 2 minutes (which I think it shouldn't) to display the result. The result will return about 5400++ records. Is there any way to redesign the query so that it will be able to execute a bit faster? Thank you for help!

My current query is:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT MasterDescription FROM sys_master_code WHERE MasterId = mktg_account.CategoryId) AS CustomerCategory, 
(CASE WHEN mktg_account.BusinessSourceId = 97 THEN mktg_account.BusinessSourceOthers ELSE (SELECT MasterDescription FROM sys_master_code WHERE MasterId = mktg_account.BusinessSourceId) END) AS BusinessSource, 
(SELECT TreeName FROM sys_tree WHERE TreeId = mktg_account.TreeId) AS PhaseName, 
(SELECT SolicitorName FROM sys_solicitor WHERE sys_solicitor.SolicitorId =(SELECT SolicitorId FROM mktg_spa WHERE mktg_spa.AccountId = mktg_account.AccountId)) AS SolicitorName, 
(SELECT MasterCode FROM sys_master_code WHERE sys_master_code.MasterId = mktg_account.AgentCompany) AS AgentCompanyText, 
(SELECT MasterCode FROM sys_master_code WHERE sys_master_code.MasterId = mktg_account.FinancialTypeId) AS FinanceSource, 
(SELECT UserName FROM sys_user WHERE UserId = mktg_account.CreatedBy) AS CreatedByName 
FROM mktg_account
WHERE TreeId IN (SELECT TreeId FROM sys_user_access_right WHERE UserId = 4)
AND IsApproved = '1' AND IsDeleted <>'1'
ORDER BY AccountNo

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mktg_account (
  AccountId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  AccountNo varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  AccountStatus varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  TreeId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  SalesDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PurchasePrice double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  SalesPersonId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  FinancialTypeId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  BillingCustomerId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  EventId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  CategoryId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  RealEstateAgentId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  BusinessSourceId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  BusinessSourceOthers varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  SalesPromotionId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  Remarks text,
  AgentName varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  AgentCompany varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  AgentContact varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  AgentRemarks text,
  CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CreatedBy int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PurgedDateTime datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PurgedBy int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PurgedIP varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  IsDeleted tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  IsApproved tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  IsPurge tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (AccountId)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sys_master_code (
  MasterId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  MasterType varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  MasterCode varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  MasterDescription varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CreatedBy int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  CreatedIP varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  IsDeleted tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  IsApproved tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  IsActive varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  PRIMARY KEY (MasterId)
) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sys_tree (
  TreeId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Tree Running Id',
  TreeName varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  IsDeleted tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 = deleted',
  PRIMARY KEY (TreeId)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sys_solicitor (
  SolicitorId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Running id number',
  SolicitorCode varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  SolicitorName varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  SolicitorType varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ContactPerson varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PhoneNo varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'phone number',
  Email varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'email address',
  CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CreatedBy int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  IsDeleted tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 = deleted',
  IsApproved tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 = waiting approval',
  PRIMARY KEY (SolicitorId)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sys_user (
  UserId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'User Running Id',
  UserLoginId varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User Name For Log In',
  UserName varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User Real Name',
  Password varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Password For Log in',
  EmailAddress varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  IsDeleted tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 = deleted',
  CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Date and time this record created',
  CreatedBy int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  IsApproved tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 = waiting approval',
  IsActive varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  PRIMARY KEY (UserId)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sys_user_access_right (
  UserId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TreeId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (UserId,TreeId),
  KEY FK_SysUserAccessRight_SysTree (TreeId)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mktg_spa (
  SpaId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  AccountId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  SPADate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  AgreementNo varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  AgreementStatus varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  AgreementDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  SPAReference varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  SolicitorId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  SolicitorRefNo varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  TitleDetailReason varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  Remark text,
  CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CreatedBy int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  IsDeleted tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  IsApproved tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (SpaId)
)
```

I run EXPLAIN and it show the table :[Query Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fkdP.jpg)

Comment: First might be to create indexes, but do show the query plan. Without that it's quite hard to say anything.

Comment: where is `mktg_spa` and anything else missing

Comment: Sorry I already added mktg_spa in the question @Drew

Comment: I run EXPLAIN and it show the image attached. I have no idea why the query will be running so slow when retrieve data. @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Wow, you really don't like joins, do you :-P Joins will most likely be a lot faster, I'll make you a version.

Comment: A bunch of correlated subqueries are always going to be slow compared with uncorrelated alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `join` instead of subqueries. Written with `join`, your query would look like

```
SELECT mktg_account.*,
  tbCustomerCategory.MasterDescription as CustomerCategory, 
  (CASE WHEN mktg_account.BusinessSourceId = 97 
   THEN mktg_account.BusinessSourceOthers 
   ELSE tbBusinessSource.MasterDescription 
   END) AS BusinessSource, 
  sys_tree.TreeName as PhaseName, 
  sys_solicitor.SolicitorName,
  tbAgentCompanyText.MasterCode as AgentCompanyText,
  tbFinanceSource.MasterCode as FinanceSource,
  sys_user.UserName as CreatedByName 
from mktg_account
left join sys_master_code as tbCustomerCategory on tbCustomerCategory.MasterId = mktg_account.CategoryId
left join sys_master_code as tbBusinessSource on tbBusinessSource.MasterId = mktg_account.BusinessSourceId
left join sys_tree on sys_tree.TreeId = mktg_account.TreeId
left join mktg_spa on mktg_spa.AccountId = mktg_account.AccountId
left join sys_solicitor on sys_solicitor.SolicitorId = mktg_spa.SolicitorId
left join sys_master_code as tbAgentCompanyText on tbAgentCompanyText.MasterId = mktg_account.AgentCompany
left join sys_master_code as tbFinanceSource on tbFinanceSource.MasterId = mktg_account.FinancialTypeId
left join sys_user on sys_user.UserId = mktg_account.CreatedBy
join sys_user_access_right on sys_user_access_right.TreeId = mktg_account.TreeId 
WHERE sys_user_access_right.UserId = 4
AND mktg_account.IsApproved = '1' AND mktg_account.IsDeleted <> '1'
ORDER BY mktg_account.AccountNo;
```

And you are missing an index on `mktg_spa`, so add it:

```
create index idx_mktg_spa_AccountId on mktg_spa (AccountId);
```

(You might want to try this first, it might already improve your query enough without converting it to `join`).

There might be some potential for an index on `mktg_account`, but it really depends on your data. If most of your rows are "deleted" or "not approved", you can try e.g.

```
create index idx_mktg_account_IsApprovedAccountNoIsDeleted 
on mktg_account (IsApproved, AccountNo, IsDeleted);
```

But if your query returns more than just a small percentage of your rows, this index might actually slow down your query, so test without it first.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!! The query runs a lot faster after adding index on mktg_spa! I found out that using subquery and join takes the same amount of time to retrieve the records! Thousand thanks for help !

Comment: Hi. I want a question want to ask you. What if I want to filter a unit number based on user key in. Where should I add the condition?

Comment: @chonglt It's not clear what you are trying to do. Generally, you filter in a "where"-condition. To filter e.g. for a username, you could use `where ... and sys_user.UserName = 'chongIt'` if you use my `left join` version or `where ... and (SELECT UserName FROM sys_user WHERE UserId = mktg_account.CreatedBy) = 'chongIt'` if you use your original code. For whatever your unit number or user key are, what tables they come from and how they should depend on each other, you have to do a similar thing. (If you use your code, it might get a little tricky to combine several tables in one condition).

Comment: Hi. I have just updated my questions. I am able to filter by using subquery. But how to change my subquery to LEFT JOIN so that it can retrieve records faster? Thank you for you help!

Comment: @chongIt Please do not edit your question to make it a whole new question. This purpose of this site is not only to answer your specific question, but also to help others with the same problem. Noone will be able to follow this thread here if you change the question and the answers here are for a different question. Revert your changes, make a new question, add the link here in a comment, I (and the advantage then: someone else too) can have a look at this later.

Comment: And on a side note: I already made you a `left join` version for your original problem. Maybe make this change first. You should really use joins. (That were the first words in my answer for a reason).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to rewrite the whole thing for you, but here's a start. Appropriately indexed, this solution will be orders of magnitude faster than what you currently have...

```
SELECT a.*
     , c.MasterDescription CustomerCategory
  FROM mktg_account a
  JOIN sys_master_code c
    ON c.MasterId = a.CategoryId
  JOIN sys_user_access_right r
    ON r.TreeId = a.TreeId 
 WHERE r.UserId = 4
   AND a.IsApproved = 1 
   AND IsDeleted <> 1
 ORDER 
    BY a.AccountNo
```